# Is there analog of memset in go?

Tags: go, slice, memset

In C++ I can initialize an array with some value using [memset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa246471%28v=vs.60%29.aspx):

```
const int MAX = 1000000;
int is_prime[MAX]

memset(is_prime, 1, sizeof(is_prime))
```

What memset does, crudely can be described as filling the array with some value, but doing this really really fast.

In go I can do `is_prime := make([]int, 1000000)`, but this will create a slice with all 0, in the similar manner I can use `new([1000000]int)`, but nothing will allow me to create an array/slice with all 1 or any other non-zero element.

Of course I can use a loop to populate it with the value later, but the main purpose of `memset` is that it is way way faster than the loop.

So do Go programmers have a `memset` analog (fast way of initializing array to some non-zero value)?

Comment: You could use [`runtime.duffzero`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/7e0c11c32fb1c7515c52b6ebe9db0d77c70b63d2/src/runtime/duff_amd64.s) with some other value than `0` in AX. Also see [mkduff.go](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/2b7505e28a50f49e85c3e0812a4c4f287b8dfa30/src/runtime/mkduff.go).

Comment: With any good compiler the loop is as fast as memset

Comment: Your `memset` doesn't initialize all elements to `1` either.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you have timings for performance of `memset` vs loop?

Comment: @edc65 it is a common myth that a loop will be as fast as memset. In a modern world with special cache control and SIMD instructions, memset can run significantly faster on large buffers than any simple loop over scalar registers. This started being true with the PowerPC in the '90s, and moved to Intel with the Pentium III, and is also true on ARM with NEON instructions.
That being said: The go compiler is explicitly NOT spending time optimizing much, because it's supposed to prioritize fast compile times.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The simplest solution with a loop would look like this:

```
func memsetLoop(a []int, v int) {
    for i := range a {
        a[i] = v
    }
}
```

There is no `memset` support in the standard library, but we can make use of the built-in [`copy()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#copy) which is highly optimized.

#### With repeated `copy()`

We can set the first element manually, and start copying the already set part to the unset part using `copy()`; where the already set part gets bigger and bigger every time (doubles), so the number of iterations is `log(n)`:

```
func memsetRepeat(a []int, v int) {
    if len(a) == 0 {
        return
    }
    a[0] = v
    for bp := 1; bp < len(a); bp *= 2 {
        copy(a[bp:], a[:bp])
    }
}
```

This solution was inspired by the implementation of [`bytes.Repeat()`](http://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Repeat). If you just want to create a new `[]byte` filled with the same values, you can use the `bytes.Repeat()` function. You can't use that for an existing slice or slices other than `[]byte`, for that you can use the presented `memsetRepeat()`.

In case of small slices `memsetRepeat()` may be slower than `memsetLoop()` (but in case of small slices it doesn't really matter, it will run in an instant).

Due to using the fast `copy()`, `memsetRepeat()` will be much faster if the number of elements grows.

Benchmarking these 2 solutions:

```
var a = make([]int, 1000) // Size will vary

func BenchmarkLoop(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        memsetLoop(a, 10)
    }
}

func BenchmarkRepeat(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        memsetRepeat(a, 11)
    }
}
```

#### Benchmark results

100 elements: **~1.15 times faster**

```
BenchmarkLoop   20000000                81.6 ns/op
BenchmarkRepeat 20000000                71.0 ns/op
```

1,000 elements: **~2.5 times faster**

```
BenchmarkLoop    2000000               706 ns/op
BenchmarkRepeat  5000000               279 ns/op
```

10,000 elements: **~2 times faster**

```
BenchmarkLoop     200000              7029 ns/op
BenchmarkRepeat   500000              3544 ns/op
```

100,000 elements: **~1.5 times faster**

```
BenchmarkLoop      20000             70671 ns/op
BenchmarkRepeat    30000             45213 ns/op
```

The highest performance gain is around 3800-4000 elements where it is **~3.2 times faster**.

Comment: thanks for the answer. It looks strange that theoretically you can get `log(n)` but practically approximately only 2 times faster.

Comment: @SalvadorDali The number of iterations is `log(n)`, but each `copy()` in the subsequent iteration has to do twice as many work (copy twice as many elements). So it's not only the iteration count that counts.

Comment: A small note here, there is [this optimisation](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/f03c9202c43e0abb130669852082117ca50aa9b1) that exists in the Go compiler.

Comment: Run at Linux 3.10.0 with amd64 go 1.14 and result is:
```goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: -
BenchmarkLoop-4          1949619               573 ns/op
BenchmarkRepeat-4         785382              1359 ns/op
```

Answer (score 7):

According to [this bug](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/5373) titled "optimize memset idiom" there is no way to do this in Go other than with a loop. The issue was closed on 9 Jan 2013 with this post

> I consider this fixed. Optimizing non-zero cases isn't very
>   interesting.
>
> We can open another bug if people feel strongly about doing more.

So the solution is to use a loop as already covered by icza.

There is [bytes.Repeat](http://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Repeat) but that also just uses a loop:

```
func Repeat(b []byte, count int) []byte {
    nb := make([]byte, len(b)*count)
    bp := copy(nb, b)
    for bp < len(nb) {
        copy(nb[bp:], nb[:bp])
        bp *= 2
    }
    return nb
}
```

Comment: Note that C's implementation is also "just" a loop. Only it makes sure that it's word-aligned and writes word-by-word instead of the width of the data type in question.

Comment: In C it will probably compile down to a specific instruction on x86 though, so not really a loop - i.e the compiler intrinsic for memset