# How do I initialize an array without using a for loop in Go?

Tags: arrays, go, initialization, slice

I have an array `A` of boolean values, indexed by integers `0` to `n`, all initially set to `true`.

My current implementation is :

```
for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
    A[i] = true
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why would you want to avoid a for loop?

Comment: To reduce execution time.

Answer (score 20):

Using a `for` loop is the simplest solution. Creating an array or slice will always return you a zeroed value. Which in case of `bool` means all values will be `false` (the zero value of type `bool`).

Note that using a [Composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) you can create and initialize a slice or array, but that won't be any shorter:

```
b1 := []bool{true, true, true}
b2 := [3]bool{true, true, true}
```

If you don't want to use a `for` loop, you can make it a little shorter by introducing a constant for the value `true`:

```
const T = true
b3 := []bool{T, T, T}
```

If `n` is big, `for` is the simplest solution.

Or you could switch the logic of your application, and use the array or slice to store the negated values in the slice, and that way the *"all-false"* zero value would be a good initial value. What I mean is that if your slice is to store if files are *present*, you could change the logic so the slice stores whether files are *missing*:

```
presents := []bool{true, true, true, true, true, true}

// Is equivalent to:

missings := make([]bool, 6) // All false
// missing=false means not missing, means present)
```

Also note that filling an array or slice with a specific value is known as a "memset" operation. Go does not have a builtin function for that, but for an efficient solution see this question:

[Is there analog of memset in go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30614165/is-there-analog-of-memset-in-go)

Answer (score 0):

Make initilization using range function without knowing the number of elements in the array.

```
for i,_:=range(A){A[i] = true}
```

Comment: for i := range A [ A[i] = true }