# Store value in an array

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I am fairly new to Go. I have coded in JavaScript where I could do this:

```
var x = [];
x[0] = 1;
```

This would work fine. But in Go, I am trying to implement the same thing with Go syntax. But that doesn't help. I need to have a array with unspecified index number.

I did this:

```
var x []string
x[0] = "name"
```

How do I accomplish that?

Comment: have you gone to [gotour](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1)? check [this](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/6) out

Comment: There's still index number specified.

Comment: the syntax that you're using is for slices (dynamic arrays), if you want arrays you would indicate the array size

Comment: Is there any other way I can store value in array without specifying the value of n when the array is initialized?- thank you

Comment: this is how you do it: `arr := [...]string{"foo", "bar"}` provided that the size of array is fixed, means it can't grow or shrink

Comment: I  don't know why I got a negative vote. At least I deserve to know the reason... :(

Comment: @camoflage The downvote was because if you had google "go arrays" the first result would have been the official documentation and if you read it you wouldn't have made this question. You should always try to do some research before asking here. Also when starting with a new language it's important to go through the documentation and try to learn the basics. Go is very well documented and the original authors have written small posts detailing how to use all the basics of the language

Comment: @camoflage The best thing you can do when starting to program in go is go through the [tour of go](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1) it takes like 20 minutes to go through it, and it covers all the basics of the language with examples that you can edit and run right there to get to know the language. [Here](https://blog.golang.org/index) you can find all the blog posts on the go blog. Some of them, specially the old ones, talk about how to best use the language and how to use slices, concurrency, channels, maps, etc.. I really recommend spending a couple of hours just looking around.

Answer (score 4):

When you type:

```
var x []string
```

You create a *slice*, which is similar to an array in Javascript. But unlike Javascript, a slice has a set length and capacity. In this case, you get a `nil` slice which has the length and capacity of 0.

A few examples of how you can do it:

```
x := []string{"name"}   // Creates a slice with length 1

y := make([]string, 10) // Creates a slice with length 10
y[0] = "name"           // Set the first index to "name". The remaining 9 will be ""

var z []string          // Create an empty nil slice
z = append(z, "name")   // Appends "name" to the slice, creating a new slice if required
```

More indepth reading about slices:
[Go slices usage and internals](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)

Comment: i think this is what OP needs

Comment: still I have to specify the number 10. Still the problem exists right?

Comment: there is no problem with that, slices can grow and shrink as needed, that is how you do it in go

Comment: @camoflage No. I showed 3 cases. In the `y` case, I specified the length. Just showing how you create a slice of a specific length. It is all depending on your use case.

Comment: Brililant, that perfectly solves my problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript arrays are *dynamic* in the sense that if you set the element of an array using an index which is greater than or equal to its length (current number of elements), the array will be *automatically* extended to have the required size to set the element (so the index you use will become the array's new length).

[Arrays](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Array_types) and [slices](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types) in Go are not that dynamic. When setting elements of an array or slice, you use an [index expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions) to designate the element you want to set. In Go you can only use index values that are in range, which means the index value must be `0 <= index < length`.

In your code:

```
var x []string
x[0] = "name"
```

The first line declares a variable named `x` of type `[]string`. This is a slice, and its value will be `nil` (the [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) of all slice types, because you did not provide an initialization value). It will have a length of 0, so the index value `0` is out of range as it is not less that the length.

If you know the length in advance, create your array or slice with that, e.g.:

```
var arr [3]string           // An array with length of 3
var sli = make([]string, 3) // A slice with length of 3
```

After the above declarations, you can refer to (read or write) values at indicies `0`, `1`, and `2`.

You may also use a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) to *create* and *initialize* the array or slice in one step, e.g.

```
var arr = [3]string{"one", "two", "three"} // Array
var sli = []string{"one", "two", "three"}  // Slice
```

You can also use the builtin [`append()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append) function to add a new element to the end of a slice. The `append()` function allocates a new, bigger array/slice under the hood if needed. You also need to assign the return value of `append()`:

```
var x []string
x = append(x, "name")
```

If you want dynamic "arrays" similar to arrays of JavaScript, the map is a similar construct:

```
var x = map[int]string{}
x[0] = "name"
```

(But a map also needs initialization, in the above example I used a composite literal, but we could have also written `var x = make(map[int]string)`.)

You may assign values to keys without having to declare the intent in prior. But know that maps are not slices or arrays, maps typically not hold values for contiguous ranges of index keys (but may do so), and maps do not maintain key or insertion order. See [Why can't Go iterate maps in insertion order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28930416/why-cant-go-iterate-maps-in-insertion-order/28931555#28931555) for details.

Must read blog post about arrays and slices: [Go Slices: usage and internals](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)

Recommended questions / answers for a better understanding:

[Why have arrays in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38645175/why-have-arrays-in-go/38645895#38645895)

[How do I initialize an array without using a for loop in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32785319/how-do-i-initialize-an-array-without-using-a-for-loop-in-go/32785452#32785452)

[How do I find the size of the array in go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35937828/how-do-i-find-the-size-of-the-array-in-go/35939008#35939008)

[Keyed items in golang array initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36302441/keyed-items-in-golang-array-initialization/36302875#36302875)

[Are golang slices pass by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993688/are-golang-slices-pass-by-value/39993797#39993797)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please use **var x [length]string;** (where length is size of the array you want) instead of **var x []string;** ?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using arrays. It is seldom you work with arrays in go.

Comment: length is still a specified value which I have to scecify before the array is initialized, right?

Comment: @camoflage Just beware that this answer is about *arrays* and not *slices*. They might look similar in syntax, the only differences being the extra length, but they behave quite different. An array is the underlying "storage" for a slice.

Answer (score 0):

In Go defining a variable like `var x=[]int` creates a slice of type integer. Slices are dynamic and when you want to add an integer to the slice, you have to append it like `x = append(x, 1)` (or `x = append(x, 2, 3, 4)` for multiple).

As srxf mentioned, have you done the Go tour? There is a page about [slices](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/15).

Answer (score -1):

I found out that the way to do it is through a dynamic array. Like this

```
type mytype struct {
  a string
}

func main() {
  a := []mytype{mytype{"name1"}}
  a = append(a, mytype{"name 2"})

fmt.Println(a);
}
```

golang playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/owPHdQ6Y6e