# Define a []byte without hex.DecodeString

Tags: string, go, byte, slice

I'm working with a HID driver, and this driver reads onto a `[]byte` buffer one of a few different reports. When I use `hex.EncodeToString(buffer)`, it will return a string looking like either `0000` or `0100` or `0200`, etc. I want to check, using a switch, against the input from the HID device, and so I want to predefine these possibilities, up outside the `main()`, how should I proceed?

I've tried these possibilities:

```golang
var LEFT []byte = []byte('0000')
// or
var LEFT []byte = `0000`
// or 
var LEFT []byte = '0000'
// or
var LEFT []byte = '\x00\x00' // from the %q Printf verb
```

The alternative is that I call `hex.DecodeString("0000")` inside the main() function.

**Edit**

A note on the solution offered, the `EncodeToString` hex `0000` or `0100` is not *four* bytes but rather *two*:

`"\x01"` == `"01"` == `'1'`

so I can use, in order to get 0100, or 0200, as suggested:

```golang
var LEFT []byte{1,0}
// or 
var LEFT []byte("\x01\x00")
```

Comment: _"... but this involves error checking, and I was hoping to set them aside."_ If you want to work / program in Go, get used to error checking. Else you'll make your (Go) life miserable...

Comment: Oh and I do love the error checking, I meant, I didn't want to error check for a DecodeString for which I was sure to succeed in, that is, I wanted to define the []byte before compiling, with a value I was already sure would not give me an error.

Comment: If you know it won't fail, you may provide a `MustDecode()` helper function. For details see answer [Go: multiple value in single-value context](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28233172/1705598).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the following:

```
var (
    left = []byte{0, 0}
    right = []byte{1, 0}
    // ... and so on
)
```

If you want to write it on hex:

```
var (
    left = []byte{0x00, 0x00}
    right = []byte{0x01, 0x00}
    // ... and so on
)
```

You can also convert a string to a []byte:

```
var (
    left = []byte("\x00\x00")
    right = []byte("\x01\x00")
)
```

Use these variables in a switch statement like this:

```
switch {
case bytes.Equal(v, left):
    fmt.Println("left")
case bytes.Equal(v, right): 
    fmt.Println("right"
}
```

It looks like you are working with 2 byte numbers encoded in little-endian format. If so, you can [decode the bytes to an integer](https://godoc.org/encoding/binary#LittleEndian):

```
const (
    left = 0
    right = 1
)

switch binary.LittleEndian.Uint16(byteSlice) {
case left:
    fmt.Println("left")
case right:
    fmt.Println("right")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Defining a `[]byte` is easiest and recommended to do with a [Composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) as Mellow Marmot suggested. Note that the composite literal also has the advantage that you may use optional indices in the literal, and values for "missing" indices will be the zero value of the element type (`0` in case of `byte`). And also if you need a `[]byte` full of zeros, you don't need to list the elements, you can just `make` an "empty" slice.

So for example you may also create your slices like this:

```
var (
    left  = make([]byte, 2) // will be [0, 0]
    right = []byte{1: 1}    // will be [0, 1]
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(left, right)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/e4ntQZraSg)):

```
[0 0] [0 1]
```

Also know that `string` values can be directly converted to `[]byte` which results in the byte sequence of the UTF-8 encoded bytes of the `string` (this is how Go stores strings in memory).

So if you can provide a `string` literal which has the UTF-8 encoded byte sequence that you need, you can simply [convert](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) it to `[]byte`. And since interpreted [string literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals) may contain escape sequences, it's easier than you think:

> The three-digit octal (*\nnn*) and two-digit hexadecimal (*\xnn*) escapes represent individual bytes of the resulting string...

So you may also specify your byte values encoded in a `string` like this:

```
// With octal escapes
var (
    left  = []byte("\000\000")
    right = []byte("\001\000")
)

// With hexa escapes
var (
    left2  = []byte("\x00\x00")
    right2 = []byte("\x01\x00")
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(left, right)
    fmt.Println(left2, right2)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/sjhQbz3pC0)):

```
[0 0] [1 0]
[0 0] [1 0]
```

See related questions:

[GO explicit array initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38783260/go-explicit-array-initialization)

[Keyed items in golang array initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36302441/keyed-items-in-golang-array-initialization)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use []byte in `switch` because slices are not comparable, strings are.
So seams just

```
const LEFT = `0000`
```