# How to create a string of arbitrary length

Tags: string, go

I want to create a dummy string of a given length to do a performance test. For example I want to first test with 1 KB of string and then may be 10 KB of string etc. I don't care which character (or rune?) it gets filled with. I understand that a string in Go is backed by byte array. So, I want the final string to be backed by a byte array of size equivalent of 1 KB (if I give 1024 as the argument).

For example, I tried the brute force code below:

```
...
    oneKBPayload := createPayload(1024, 'A')
...
//I don't mind even if the char argument is removed and 'A' is used for example 
func createPayload(len int, char rune) string {
    payload := make([]byte, len)
    for i := 0; i < len; i++ {
        payload = append(payload, byte(char))
    }
    return string(payload[:])
}
```

and it produced a result of (for 10 length)

```
"\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000AAAAAAAAAA"
```

I realize that it has something to do with the encoding. But how to fix this so that I create any string which is backed by a byte array of the given length so that when I write it over the network, I generate the intended payload.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `createPayload()` creates a byte slice with the given length, which is filled with zeros by default ([zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value)). Then you append `len` number of `runes` to this slice, so the result will be double the length you intend to create (given the `rune` is less than `127`), and that's why you see zeros then followed by the `'A'` rune when printed.

If you change it to:

```
payload := make([]byte, 0, len)
```

Then the result will be what you want.

But easier would be to simply use [`strings.Repeat()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Repeat) which repeats a given `string` value `n` times. Repeat a one-rune (or more specifically a one-byte) `string` value `n` times, and you get what you want:

```
s := strings.Repeat("A", 10)
fmt.Println(len(s), s)
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/SJMMeLHYibf)):

```
10 AAAAAAAAAA
```

If you don't care about the content of the `string` only about its length, then simply convert a byte slice like this:

```
s := string(make([]byte, 1024))
fmt.Println(len(s))
```

Or alternatively like this:

```
s2 := string([]byte{1023: 0})
fmt.Println(len(s2))
```

Both prints `1024`. Try them on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/CFf-UpczzTy).

If you do care about the content and you already have a byte slice allocated, this is how you can efficiently fill it: [Is there analog of memset in go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30614165/is-there-analog-of-memset-in-go/30614594#30614594)

Comment: Thank you! I tried strings.C (in GoLand) and couldn't find any Create kind of method. Didn't occur to me to look for Repeat method (strings.R would have suggested that). I will accept the answer in 5 mins (SOF restriction).